# Resizing a sprite by adding transparent pixels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, sprite

The reason I wish to do so is that Unity has a nice DTX5 format that reduces the file size by a lot. But to get that, I need a sprite that's size is - both for height and width - a multiple of 4. 
So I thought I create a new texture with the desired size, load its pixels with the original's pixels and make a sprite out of it that I save as an `asset`. 
The issue is that while saving the **texture** works, I get the same texture with the proper sizes, saving the **sprite** doesn't work. It spits out something, but that isn't even close to what I need.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResizeSprites
{
    public void Resize(Sprite sprite)
    {
        int _hei, _wid;
        //getting the closest higher values that are a multiple of 4. 
        for (_hei = sprite.texture.height; _hei % 4 != 0; _hei++) ;
        for (_wid = sprite.texture.width; _wid % 4 != 0; _wid++) ;
        //creating the new texture. 
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(_wid, _hei,TextureFormat.RGBA32,false);
        //tex.alphaIsTransparency = true;
        //tex.EncodeToPNG();

       //giving the new texture the "improper" ratio sprite texture's pixel info
        //pixel by pixel.
        for (int wid = 0; wid < sprite.texture.width; wid++)
        {
            for (int hei = 0; hei < sprite.texture.height; hei++)
            {
                tex.SetPixel(wid, hei, sprite.texture.GetPixel(wid, hei));
            }
        }
        //saving the asset. the save works, was used for both meshes as well as textures. 
        Sprite n_spr = Sprite.Create(tex,
            new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height),
            new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
        AssetSaver.CreateAsset(n_spr, sprite.name + "_dtx5");
    }

}
```

And here are my results:

[image: original sprite]

[image: the sad outcome]

The first one is the original sprite, and the second is what I was given.

**Edit:** Even if I don't save my creation, just instantiate it as a `GameObject`, the result is still the same ugly one.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Texture2D.Apply()` after your for loop?
 [Texture2D.Apply](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html)

Comment: Also, look into `GetPixels()` and `SetPixels()`.  They accept an `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` and will transfer the color data without the need for a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tomorrow morning I start by checking this out, I haven't tried any of those.

Comment: Have you considered using an external editor?

Comment: @Draco18s If I get you, you mean I should edit those images outside Unity and reimport?

Comment: @agiro Yes. If you right click on the existing file, show in explorer, it'll pop up a file browser window to the asset directly. You can just edit the texture there as you would any other file.

Comment: That would be viable but I got to know this compression way too late, so I have tons of textures in place. Hand-editing all of them would be a loss on the long run, not to mention this "tool"-ish I build now (alongside my sprite-to-mesh replacer) can be reused in other projects.

Comment: @Draco18s well after swapping my "hole-less" sprites with unlit meshes, I have few sprites left. Those are easily edited by hand and I plan to do so. Couple of days into coding and I forgot about the easiest solution :D thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hundreds of files would indeed be a pain to hand-edit. I'd pull out tools like Workspace Macro or GIMP filter scripts before writing a Unity script to do it. Glad you got things solved though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need all these code.`Texture2D` has a resize function so just pull the `Texture2D` from the Sprite then call the re-szie function to re-size it. That's it.

Something like this:

```
public void Resize(Sprite sprite)
{
    Texture2D tex = sprite.texture;

    tex.Resize(100, 100, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

    Sprite n_spr = Sprite.Create(tex,
        new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height),
        new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);

    AssetSaver.CreateAsset(n_spr, sprite.name + "_dtx5");
}
```

---

As for you original problem, that's because you did not call the [`Apply`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) function. Each time you modify the pixels, you are supposed to call the [`Apply`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html)  function. Finally, always use `GetPixels32` not `GetPixel` or `GetPixels`. The reason is because `GetPixels32` is extremely faster than the rest of the function.

```
public void Resize(Sprite sprite)
{
    int _hei, _wid;
    //getting the closest higher values that are a multiple of 4. 
    for (_hei = sprite.texture.height; _hei % 4 != 0; _hei++) ;
    for (_wid = sprite.texture.width; _wid % 4 != 0; _wid++) ;
    //creating the new texture. 
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(_wid, _hei, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    //tex.alphaIsTransparency = true;
    //tex.EncodeToPNG();

    //giving the new texture the "improper" ratio sprite texture's pixel info
    //pixel by pixel.

    Color32[] color = sprite.texture.GetPixels32();

    tex.SetPixels32(color);

    tex.Apply();

    //saving the asset. the save works, was used for both meshes as well as textures. 
    Sprite n_spr = Sprite.Create(tex,
        new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height),
        new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
    AssetSaver.CreateAsset(n_spr, sprite.name + "_dtx5");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The first solution does indeed create a sprite but it's all transparent :/ 
The second does that too :D Now, using my old solution with the `Apply` method it works fine. All the problem is that though I get a sprite as an asset, I can't modify texture type, the sprite mode, so no import settings where I could enforce the use of DTX5. How to save it so I can modify those?

Comment: All in all you answered my question perfectly. For runtime performance I can save at least 10% on file size without any noticable quality change according to the Profiler. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. There is also `TextureFormat.DXT5`. You can use that instead of `TextureFormat.RGBA32`. Having really tried it though.

Comment: I used that _after_ creating the new texture and applied again. Hopefully that way it works too

Comment: That looks fine.